# How many equivalents of Grignard reagent does a nitrile group consume?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, grignard-reagent, nitriles

I was looking at reactions of grignard reagent with certain kinds of compounds and came across it's reaction with nitrile group:
[image]

What I was wondering is what if we don't react the Imine formed after (1) and instead add excess of Grignard reagent? Would it consume the second equivalent as well?
I tried looking for something like this but couldn't find it anywhere. They added water after the Imine was formed to give the ketone.  I read somewhere that it might depend on the Grignard reagent, etc.

But if we consider a suitable one, would it be **possible** for the nitrile group to consume 2 equivalents of Grignard reagent?

Comment: A second eq of Grignard does not react with the imine-magnesium salt.

Comment: @Waylander how can we reason this out because there is still a pi bond between C and N right? Is it because of stability reasons? The negative formal charge on N is stabilised by (+)MgX ?

Comment: "Ketimines are, in general, less reactive than aldimines because of their low electrophilicity and the increased steric hindrance to nucleophilic attack on the C=N bond."  according to this reference  https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/ketimine

Comment: In my experience you have to activate ketimines to get organometallic reagents to add to them.